# How do I eject without the auto eject perk?

Tags: titanfall

My buddy swears he can do it on PC, but I can't seem to figure out how on my Xbox One. Can I without the perk and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll convert this from a comment to an answer, so it's helpfull to anyone regardless of platform.

It's worth noting on PC, you can hold down <kbd>X</kbd> then tap <kbd>E</kbd> to eject manually, but it will destroy your Titan even from full health.

On Xbox One, hold down [d-pad up] and repeatedly tap [X]

For Xbox 360, hold down [d-pad up] and repeatedly tap [X]

You should see an icon of the ejector seat on the bottom right of the Titan hud. Hold this button and repeatedly tap your 'interact' button.

See this screenshot for the HUD item in the bottom right.
[image]

Comment: According to the default layout for the 360 controller, d-pad up initiates the ejection sequence. I'd imagine it's exactly the same for the xbox one controller.

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado, I've edited the answer to add Xbox360 controls also. Feel free to update it with the right buttons :)

Answer (score 1):

Several of my friends have had trouble ejecting during the 'doomed' period.  It turns out they were holding 'X' (for Xbox One), instead of tapping it.

From the title, I thought this might apply, but the text says otherwise.  I'd thought I'd say this anyways, in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Regular get out - hold 'X'
Eject - tap 'X' when prompt appears.

Comment: This is helpful, actually. I always forget to tap and hold it. Then I get mauled as I'm climbing out. =\